# Index match finding the first value only

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a list of employees with duplicates and each employee has a number which represents the number of sales. I'm trying to use the following formula to extract the highest sale for a given name, but it's only extracting the first value it finds instead of going through the whole list:

=MAX(INDEX(Table1[Sales],MATCH([Name],Table1[Name],0)))

[The List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUD5J.jpg)

Comment: Please add some sample data. Its much easier to solve your problem when we can work on real data (make the names and numbers up buy keep the general structure)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an array formula like the following. Array formulas must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=MAX(IF([Name]=[@Name],[Sales]))
```

or, if you have and Office 365 subscription, you can use the new Maxifs function, like this:

```
=MAXIFS([Sales],[Name],[Name])
```

[image]